# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. While creating new instance of window form in c#

Tags: .net, winforms, window

I have MainForm (WinForm) with button called capture signature . In the `Click` event of this button, I am creating the instance CaptureSignatureForm, code as follows.

```
MainForm oSign = new MainForm(this);
oSign.ShowDialog();
```

When the form is open I capture signature, after capture, form will close.
Second time I click on the capturesignature button, it throws an error: `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"`

I'm using third party dll to capture signature.

i am getting an error at italic bold text in if condition .
 contol is object of signaturecapturedevice .
 As per third party documenetation (capabilities object is populated automatically when you
connect to the tablet.)

```
  if (control.EnsureConnected() && ***control.capabilities.LCDWidth != 0***)
            {
                this.ClientSize = new Size(tabletWidth, tabletHeight);

                if (model == Model.STU300)
                {
                    btnOk.SetBounds(tabletWidth - 80, 0, 80, tabletHeight / 3);
                    btnClear.SetBounds(tabletWidth - 80, tabletHeight / 3, 80, tabletHeight / 3);
                    btnCancel.SetBounds(tabletWidth - 80, (tabletHeight / 3) * 2, 80, tabletHeight / 3);
                }
                else
                {
                    btnOk.SetBounds(0, tabletHeight - 55, tabletWidth / 3, 55);
                    btnClear.SetBounds(tabletWidth / 3, tabletHeight - 55, tabletWidth / 3, 55);
                    btnCancel.SetBounds((tabletWidth / 3) * 2, tabletHeight - 55, tabletWidth / 3, 55);
                }
```

Comment: What happens when you debug it? where does it stop whats the code around it?, try breaking on the click of the button, and stepping into your code.

Comment: You need to show the code for launching the `CaptureSignatureForm`.

Comment: Please provide us with the full stacktrace so that we can analyze the origin of the error.

Comment: Here's a helpful tip: don't prefix your variables with `o` or any other prefix, per [.NET Naming Conventions](http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is giving exception when capabilities.LCDWidth is invoked and capabilities does not have value, either check the vendors documentation for capabilities or try to explore control.Reconnect/Close any of that sort and then try to run this